# Should I watch the K movie ("Missing Kings") before watching the second season ("Return of Kings")?

Tags: k-project

The show *K: Return of Kings* is going to be airing in fall 2015. I've seen the first season (*K*), but I haven't gotten around to watching the movie (*K: Missing Kings*) yet.

Am I good to start watching the second season right away, or do I need to watch the movie first?

(While it's often the case that movies incidental to a TV series are just sidestories that you don't *have* to watch to follow the TV series, the naming scheme here makes me wonder if that's actually the case with *K*.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should watch the movie, as it is related to the storyline of Return of The Kings (ROTK). If you don't, you will not know the major changes that have been made, nor the main villain of ROTK, nor will you know what happened to Shiro. These were all revealed in the movie. They would just allow Shiro to show up and you would not know what happened to him or how he was revived. Though it's just him

> using his powers to regenerate a body and being collected by the dying Golden king.

So yes, you should watch the movie before ROTK in order to avoid being confused by all the sudden changes in ROTK, since even the movie occurs after a time skip after the ending of the first season.